# Device specific Image handling

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage

I have a simple question. Lets say I have an about screen, where I show a company logo or app logo.

`64x64logo.png`

`128x128logo@2x.png`

about screen is loaded with `logo.png`
how do we swap high resolution image for retina based iphones

or will the system do it by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your retina device will take care of it, only you need to add 2 images in resources, one for non-ratina UI and another for ratina UI.

The only thing you need to take care is to give same name to the both the images and add @2x postfix to ratina image.

like this:

`for non-ratina device-logo.png`

`for nratina device-logo@2x.png`

Please have look at the apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html).

Comment: @Atif and Mayur. Thanks both of you. I thought so too. 

Now Will that same scenario work for any other situation, like for example custom navigation bar background image. I think so too, but I am not clear on one thing. for iphone nav bar height is 44px in portrait and 32px in landscape and for iPad it is 44px in both mode and plus retina display. I assume there is no need for device specific handling of the background image for nav bar as long as the image doesn't show much difference in the image itself. 

please correct if i am missing something. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

iOS recognizes retina images with @2x so you don't need to explicitly chose the image for different devices. If app is on a non-retina device it will choose logo.png and on a retina device logo@2x will be displayed automatically